# JS do not sort numeral object indices

Tags: javascript, loops, object

When creating an object like so

```js
let o = {}
o["prop2"] = "val"
o["prop1"] = "val"
```

The properties are stored in the order they are set, so when getting the keys of the object (`Object.keys(o)`) they are returned in their *proper* order (`["prop2", "prop1"]`). This order has wide reaching consequences as `for...in` loops use it and hence `JSON.stringify` is influenced by it as well. I want to use this behaviour for performance optimisations (like sending already sorted objects that are easier to parse).

However all this falls apart when using numeric indices. The seemingly similar object

```
let o = {}
o["2"] = "val"
o["1"] = "val"
```

does not confirm the behaviour above. Here `Object.keys(o)` returns `["1", "2"]` :(.

Can this be avoided somehow? Without pre-/post fixing all properties?

Comment: those are due to the ES specs.  due to historical reasons and for optimization techniques (integrer accesses can be highly optimized as native level array access and major libraries like React depended on it).  You can use a Map() or prefix them so they aren't integers.

Comment: Try using a [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) they will retain the order of insertion

Comment: @theblackgigant maps would work great if I could `JSON.stringify` them

Comment: you would have to deserialize it later anyways, so depending on the order is generally a bad idea. the short answer is no, and you should avoid depending on key order

Comment: @user120242 prefixing seems like an dirty fix. But I guess ill have to go with that. Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide an argument or test, that this "optimization" is actually useful and in any way producing performance gains relevant to your project's success? It sounds like yet another case of "premature optimization is the root of all evil".

Comment: @MaximilianMairinger You can use `JSON.stringify` on `map.entries()`.

Comment: @hev1 `JSON.stringify(map.entries())` isnt deep though, is it?

Comment: if optimization is the concern, arrays and integer index accesses will outperform significantly (is especially stark on V8).  but you really have to be doing a _lot_ of work on seriously large data sets for this micro-optimization to show up.  Something like "JSON lines" and incremental parsing will much sooner be the bottleneck than that.

Comment: @ASDFGerte it isnt necessarily critical. I need to sort the object anyway in a particular way before iterating over it. Doing this work on every client simply feels dumb.

Comment: @MaximilianMairinger It works fine for nested objects.

Comment: @MaximilianMairinger When it comes to performance, real world data sets and context will be needed for it to be relevant.  It can vary widely depending on all the factors from environment to data set type and size to use case.  If you're bothered that the JS engine appears to be doing extra work that you think it shouldn't, know that the engine is most likely much more optimized for handling these things than you could do manually.  The parsing and representation of data internally is not going to be orders of complexity higher and is most likely linear or constant relative to your own.

Comment: if I'm understanding your concern, it is not a concern.  ie: an indexed array struct for holding integer keys of an object map will not have higher complexity in space or time, and the perceived "extra sorting" you probably think is happening is not actually happening.  To the contrary, it is actually an optimization, esp. given that it is implementated at the native level.

Comment: My understanding is now, that you want to serialize an ordered structure, retaining that order, preferably using JSON, with the purpose of sorting once on the server, instead of once on every client. So first use an ordered structure (array, map, ...). Afterwards, the problem is how to serialize it, but `JSON.stringify`, with minimal edits compared to your object-solution, will also solve that. I was just afraid, that with "sorted objects that are easier to parse", you meant you wanted to optimize the time taken by `JSON.parse`, which would sound a lot like premature optimization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) instead to retain insertion order.

```js
let m = new Map;
m.set("2", "val");
m.set("1", "val");
m.forEach((v,k)=>console.log(k,"=",v));
```

To convert it to JSON, you can stringify the entries of the `Map`. You can use parse the string and pass the entries to the constructor of Map to convert it back.

```js
const map = new Map([
  ['foo', 10],
  ['baz', 42]
]);
let str = JSON.stringify([...map.entries()])
console.log(str);
new Map(JSON.parse(str)).forEach((v,k)=>console.log(k,"=",v));
```

You can provide an callback to JSON.stringify and JSON.parse to convert nested Map structures.

```
let m = new Map;
m.set("b", new Map([["c","d"],["e","f"], ["d", new Map([["a", 1]])]]));
let str = JSON.stringify(m, (key,val)=>{
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(val) === '[object Map]' ? [...val.entries()] : val;
});
console.log(str);
let m2 = JSON.parse(str, (key, val)=>{
    return Array.isArray(val) && Array.isArray(val[0]) ? new Map(val) : val;
});
console.log(m2);
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ob8d2uLf/1/

Comment: If the property c were a Map as well, this would fall apart, right?

Comment: @MaximilianMairinger you can implement a callback function to JSON.stringify/parse that handles it.  The "reviver"/"replacer" functions

Comment: @hev1 I would recommend using the reviver/replacer features, rather than traversing it recursively manually.  That implementation also looks really, really inefficient.

Comment: a bit of opinion here, but if it were between this and just prefixing, or having your own custom object notation for something like Map, or storing an array of keys to preserve order, I'd say maybe just prefix it and call it a day, or use array of keys if absolute performance is needed.  and choose one of these depending on what you actually need, where each one may fit a use case better than the others

Comment: @MaximilianMairinger Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/ob8d2uLf/1/